# Laravel Scout production error with TNTSearch driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-scout

Searching using the TNTSearch driver works in a Homestead environment however on production it returns error: the below error,

> `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class
>   'AlgoliaSearch\Version' not found` on
>   `vendor/laravel/scout/src/EngineManager.php:31`

However my .env has `SCOUT_DRIVER=tntsearch` and the config file scout.php has:

```php
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'tntsearch'),

'tntsearch' => [
    'storage' => storage_path(),
    'fuzziness' => env('TNTSEARCH_FUZZINESS', false),
    'fuzzy' => [
        'prefix_length' => 2,
        'max_expansions' => 50,
        'distance' => 2
    ],
    'asYouType' => false,
    'searchBoolean' => env('TNTSEARCH_BOOLEAN', false),
]
```

The problem is that I am not using Algolia search and my composer file has Scout and TNTSearch driver. The search works in my local Homestead environment just not on the production server.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver/issues/72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, I had uploaded my project but for some reason the .index  file that is needed sync'd but did not work. If this happens to you on live make sure you Git or SVN or whatever the index or run `php artisan scout:import App\\Your\\Model`

Answer (score 4):

Confirm that `SCOUT_DRIVER=tntsearch` has been added to your .env file.

For me personally, I had added `SCOUT_DRIVER=tntsearch` to my local .env file, but not my .env file for the environment with the issue. Don't forget to run `php artisan config:clear` after adding the env var.

Thanks to @m33bo for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for this. It helped me.